# How to run initialize commands in Octave?

Tags: initialization, config, octave

How do you set up Octave software to run initialization commands when it starts? For example, set the prompt (PS1) and cd to the project directory?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could

1. write a script that does the start up routines you want and call octave afterwards
2. use

   ```
   octave --persist --eval 'some_code_to_evaluate'
   ```

   or
3. set the exec path with

   ```
   octave --exec-path path_to_your_subprogramms
   ```

Personally, I wouldn't want octave to *cd* to the project directory, since projects directories can change. Furthermore, other features like the *--eval* command are not that easy to use anymore if you always have some default code running beforehand.

Answer (score 7):

I have Octave installed in `C:\Octave`, so I did what you ask in file at location `C:\Octave\3.2.4_gcc-4.4.0\share\octave\site\m\startup`. File is called ***System-wide startup file for Octave*** and code I put in there is:

```
PS1('>> ');
addpath('{$path-to-my-octave-files}');
```

But any code is OK, I guess.

Comment: In addition to system-wide startup file, there are user specific startup files. Such file is `~/.octaverc` in Linux. This seems a better choice for the current problem which seems very much user specific.